# Enviando datos en Android - cannot be referenced by a static context

Tags: java

En putExtra me salta el siguiente error `cannot be referenced by a static context` y no entiendo el por que, simplemente quiero pasar los datos a la 2º pantalla

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText dato1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText dato2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final Button boton_enviar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    final RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);



    boton_enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        String v1 = dato1.getText().toString();
        String v2 = dato2.getText().toString();

        int operador1 = Integer.parseInt(v1);
        int operador2 = Integer.parseInt(v2);
        final int suma = operador1 + operador2;
        final double resta = operador1 - operador2;
        final double multiplicacion = operador1 * operador2;
        final double division = operador1 / operador2;

        public void onClick(View v) {

                   switch(v.getId()) {
                       case R.id.boton:
                           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                           Intent.putExtra("suma",suma);

                           if (rb1.isSelected()) {


                           } else if (rb2.isChecked()) {


                           } else if (rb3.isChecked()) {


                           } else if (rb4.isChecked()) {


                           }
                           startActivity(intent);
                   }


            }
    });



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás referenciando la clase en lugar de la instancia.

Cambia  `Intent.putExtra("suma",suma);` por  `intent.putExtra("suma",suma);`

Por otro lado, el `onClickListener` lo estás agregando a `boton_enviar`, por lo que el `View` pasado a `onClick()` es siempre `boton_enviar`. No te hace falta el switch para saber de que `View` se trata.

Comment: Muchas gracias , ahora funciona pero a lo referente al switch ¿ lo quito definitivamente?

Comment: Sí, ese switch sirver cuando el activity implementa OnClickListener y a varios botones del activity le pasas al mismo activity (this) como su OnClickListener.

Comment: Perfecto! , ya esta hecho